# How do I set up ADFS 2.0 as both RP and IP

Tags: adfs2.0

I am trying to find out how to set up 2 separate versions of ADFS, one as the RP and the other as the IP.
We have 2 websites both protected by 2 different ADFS implementations.
I need to set up one ADFS to trust the other so that the users in one can have a Single sign on experience across both applications.
This seems like it should be a popular configuration but all of the information I can find uses some other type of IP, either ACS, or some other brand STS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two ADFS say A (IP) and B (RP).

A has a website X.

B has a website Y.

- Set A up as claims provider trust to B
- Set B up as a RP for A.

A has an RP which is X application.

B has an RP which is Y application.

So A has two RP.

To set this up, in the ADFS wizard for B, select "Add Claims Provider Trust" and user A's metadata.

In the ADFS wizard for A, select "Add Relying Party Trust" and user B's metadata.

Comment: So A is the RP not the actual application?

Comment: I should add that I dont really know how to do the second step.

Comment: I should add that I don't really know how to do the second step. Assuming that I manually configure (because I don't know what location the federation metadata is at or can I just use the RP ADFS Metadata location?) then what certificate should I use? does it matter? doesn't it need to be trusted back to a root certificate? I pressume I should enable support for WS-Federation Passive but what location should I give? Is it the location of the RP ADFS?

Comment: ADFS metadata is always at .../FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml. So in the wizard, use the first option and point to https://xxx/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml where the xxx is the URL of A or B. The certificates are in the metadata - you don't need to worry.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad for the help, I have it working in our Dev environment but so far no luck in the QA environment.  Stackoverflow likes you to pick answers, so I am marking this as an answer, although it is missing the last line which should read "Then spend from the next 2 weeks to the rest of your life trying to figure out why it does not work"